# Input/Output error when getting termios attributes on ttyS0 serial port

Tags: c, linux, serial-port, termios

I am writing a simple program to open the serial port `/dev/ttyS0` which is visible in `/dev`.

The code opens the serial port no problems on my PC at home but on my work machine I run into an error that returns "Input/Output Error". The error appears as a result of `tcgetattr` failing but I am unsure why as the serial port is visible. I added a verbose error printout via `libexplain` and it reported to me.

> tcgetattr(fildes = 3 "/dev/ttyS0", data = 0x7FFEEA8CEEB0) failed, Input/output error (5, EIO)

I am not sure what other information is relevant that I can provide. It is an Arch Linux system with a 5.3.8 kernel.

```
const char *port_name = "/dev/ttyS0";

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   int serial_fd, file_status;
    struct termios termSettings;
    struct sigaction act = { 0 };

    serial_fd = open(port_name, O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY | O_NONBLOCK);

    if (serial_fd < 0) {
        perror("Opening serial port failed");
        return -1;
    }

    if (tcgetattr(serial_fd, &termSettings) < 0) {
        perror("Getting terminal attributes failed");
        printf("Error reason: %s\n",  explain_tcgetattr(serial_fd, &termSettings));
        goto error;
    }
   ...
}
```

The complete source is [here](https://github.com/alxhoff/C-code-snippets/blob/3b913fc0efcb84ff9597e8874218a149cfcfb75f/tty_serial/src/main.c)

Comment: Looks like a hardware issue. Are you sure you are using the right port? Does `dmesg | grep /dev/ttyS0` report something unusual? What driver does your port use?

Comment: dmesg is empty, setserial is reporting `/dev/ttyS0, UART: unknown, Port: 0x03f8, IRQ: 4`. `/sys/class/tty/*/device/driver` is showing all of my 4 ttyS[0123] being run by the `serial8250` driver.

Comment: Do a `sudo modprobe serial-8250` and try `dmesg | grep /dev/tty` again. You are on a desktop with a multiport card, right?

Comment: lsmod is saying I don't have it in my kernel's `/lib/modules` even though CONFIG_SERIAL_8250 is enabled in my kernel build. Funnily enough I get the same result from my home PC, saying 8250 cannot be found. Both are thinkpads with docks. My work computer (with the error) is an x280 with a thunderbolt dock.

Comment: Can you switch docking stations to see if the hardware is faulty?

Comment: I'm asking because I've seen that, if the docking connector is not firmly in place or damaged the driver will not load

Comment: Try using system utilities, e.g. stty, instead of your code. If those have same issues then problem is with the system. BTW using nonblocking mode is probably the wrong choice, especially with noncanonical mode (nonblocking mode nullifies the VMIN and VTIME settings).  Sleeping while waiting for a signal to perform the read is convoluted and a waste of time & effort.  The kernel does a far more efficient job if you simply used blocking mode.

Comment: @MarcosG. Removing my dock still results in the same error. I sadly don't have another dock to test with as I think no two of us have the same series thinkpad :P 
@sawdust `stty -F /dev/ttyS0` gives the same error so it must be the hardware I guess. I also do not know too much about serial but my eventual application (FreeRTOS emulator) will have the serial traffic asynchronously transferred into freertos queues, ideally not blocking while waiting for new traffic. In this case does async make sense?

Comment: *"Does `dmesg | grep /dev/ttyS0` report something unusual?"* -- No, that's inappropriate and too restrictive; drivers don't care about the **/dev** directory while initializing.  Simplify and search for `dmesg | grep tty`.      *"setserial is reporting `/dev/ttyS0, UART: unknown,...`"* -- That might be a problem.  In  **drivers/tty/serial/serial_core.c** routine **uart_port_startup()** checks for `if (uport->type == PORT_UNKNOWN)`, which will eventually result in EIO to the user.

Comment: *"In this case does async make sense?"* -- No, because the kernel handles the async I/O when you open the serial terminal.  Your program is "reading" from a terminal buffer (typically 4K bytes) rather than the hardware. See [Linux serial drivers](http://www.linux.it/~rubini/docs/serial/serial.html)   The device driver using interrupts is buffering the received data.  Your program can fetch data from the upper-layer buffer at any pace.  Preferably use syscalls of more than just one byte.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `dmesg(1)` output you show in the comments to your question shows `UART: unknown`. It seems this can be the problem.  It is not recognizing any uart in port `0x3f8`, so you seem **not to have an uart there** (at least, not a standard or compatible one)

The message normally shows `UART: ns16550a` or similar, giving you info about the chipset installed there.  In your case, the other parameters, show as reserved by the kernel so no other device can use those.  I don't know the exact reason why the serial driver does not deallocate the resources and continues, but that's probably some legacy issue also.

PC based uarts are normally recognized by hardwired configuration only at fixed locations in the system, and are exercised (some inocuous command is sent to see if it responds to it) to be recognized, as *they are legacy devices*, predating from PnP or PCI devices, so they must be probed by software at well known places.  This is what the software is doing.

If you know there's a physical port device installed, try to use BIOS SETUP to check if the serial port has been enabled in BIOS (if it hasn't you'll not see it at all).  Enable it if it hasn't been, and try again.