# Why when I try set serial port, function return "Input/output error"?

Tags: c++, linux, linux-kernel, serial-port, embedded

I try set in c++ some serial port, but when I try function tcsetatrr, its return error -1. Port opens without problems.

```
char port_name[] = "/dev/ttyS1";

int port = open(port_name, O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY | O_NDELAY);
if(port < 0){
    std::cout << "Cant open port" << std::endl;
    return;
}

struct termios settings;
tcgetattr(port, &settings);

cfgetispeed(&settings);
//std::cout << settings.c_cflag;

//Baudrate
cfsetispeed(&settings, B115200);
cfsetospeed(&settings, B115200);

//Data bits
settings.c_cflag &= ~CSIZE;
settings.c_cflag |= CS8;

//Parity
settings.c_cflag |= ~PARENB;

//Stop bit
settings.c_cflag &= ~CSTOPB;

//Flow control
settings.c_cflag |= ~CRTSCTS;
settings.c_iflag &= ~(IXON | IXOFF | IXANY);

int er = tcsetattr(port, TCSANOW, &settings);
if (er<0) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Error openinig: %s\n", strerror(errno));
}

close(port);
```

output:

```
Input/output error
```

How can I fix that? I was running code as root. The problem is not in the configuration of the settings structure because after commenting it out, I get the same error

Comment: Did you try running the code as root, you might not have rights to configure the device.

Comment: *"The problem is not in the configuration of the settings structure because..."* -- Then post the *minimal*, reproducible example.  Your program should also be checking the return code from **tcgetattr()**.

Answer (score 1):

The most likely answer is that [you don't really have a serial device /dev/ttyS1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58952752/input-output-error-when-getting-termios-attributes-on-ttys0-serial-port). Try /dev/ttyS0 instead. I have the same deal on my PC.

I see a few additional problems here.

You don't check if `tcgetattr()` succeeds, so don't be so sure you even get to `tcsetattr()`.

Calling `settings.c_cflag |= ~PARENB;` or `settings.c_cflag |= ~CRTSCTS;` is most likely **not** what you want to do (will raise *all* flags except the selected one).